# Google ads show on localhost but not on live web server

Tags: wordpress, server, xampp, adsense

I have a wordpress website, which is approved by google adsense. However, I decided to move it to a home web server now. What i did so far:

1. I created a localhost using xampp on windows 7.
2. I opened a port and linked the localhost to my router external ip. (I have not linked the website to my domain yet, so i access the website by its ip)

The webiste is running well now except for the ads. They show up when the website is on localhost, but there is only a blank space when i change the website url from localhost to my router ip address.

Do you have any ideas whether this can be fixed since i could not find any info about this? Thank you very much in advance for any information shared!

Answer (score 0):

When you just created a new ads in google adsense you must wait a few minutes before they will show correctly on web page.

Comment: Hi Krystian, I am using the old ads which are still displayed on the old host. However, my host expires next week, so the question is will these ads show up on the new host? Maybe i need to create new ones?

Comment: Now I see you have this problem when you change localhost to your IP address. I think when you publish (upload to server) everything will working great :)